# ReactJS: Reset-Render Child Component on Parent state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a strange - at least for me :-) - issue with my Components.

I have a `map()` function generating a list of Child elements. When I change the filter and the list repopulates the state of the children remain as it was. For example, if the second Alumni Child Component has state `{height:auto}` the new second Allumni Child has again `{height: auto}`.

I find it really odd because this is not the same element, it's a new element corresponding to another person, with new content passed through props.

Long story short how do I force my new Child elements to have initial state {height: 0}?

There is a lot of details hidden but the core of my Parent App is as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterName: "",
            filterInitial: "Α",
            ....
            filteredGraduates:[],
            loaderVisible:true
        };
        this.updateInitial = this.updateInitial.bind(this)
        ...
      }

    componentDidMount(){
      ...
    }

    updateInitial(letter) {
      if (letter==='*'){
        this.setState({
          filterInitial: "*",
          filteredGraduates : [...graduates]
        })
      }else{
        this.setState({
        filterInitial: letter,
        filteredGraduates : graduates.filter( (graduate) => graduate.Surname.charAt(0)===letter )
      })
      }
      console.log('this is the letter: ',letter);
    }


    render() {

        return (
          <div className="app">
          <div className="filters">
            <div className="name-pagination">
              <span 
                onClick={ () => this.updateInitial('*')}
                className={'*'==this.state.filterInitial? 'active': ''}
                >Α - Ω
              </span>
              <hr/>
              {letters.map( (letter) => {
              return(
                  <span 
                  onClick={ () => this.updateInitial(letter)}
                  className={letter==this.state.filterInitial? 'active': ''}
                  >{letter}</span>
                )
               }
              )}
            </div>

            </div>
          </div> 
          {this.state.loaderVisible && <Loader /> }  
          {!this.state.loaderVisible &&  <div className="graduates-wrapper">
            {this.state.filteredGraduates
            .sort( (x,y) => x.Surname.localeCompare(y.Surname) )
            .map( (graduate) => {
              return(
                <div>
                  <Allumni
                  key={graduate.id}
                  ....  a lot of props ...
                  />               
                </div>
              )
            })
            }
          </div>}

          </div>
        );
      }
  }
```

and my Child is:

```
class Allumni extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height:0
        };
        this.updateHeight = this.updateHeight.bind(this)

    }

    updateHeight() {        
        this.setState({
            height: this.state.height === 0 ? 'auto' : 0,
        });
    };

    render() {

        const {
            name,
            surName,
            .......
        } = this.props

        return (
        <div className="allumni-wrapper">
            <div className="allumni-main-info">
                <span className="allumni-surname">{surName}</span><br/><span className="allumni-name">{name}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="allumni-extra">
                <span className="allumni-year">{yearOf}</span><br/>
                <span className="allumni-job">{job}</span> / <span className="allumni-home-city">{homeCity}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="allumni-details">
            <AnimateHeight
                duration={ 500 }
                height={ this.state.height }
                >
                <p><span className="attribute-name">... {fatherName}</p>
                <p><span className="attribute-name">...{studies}</p>
                ....
                </AnimateHeight>
            </div>
            <div className="allumni-actions" onClick={this.updateHeight}>
                <AccountCardDetailsOutlineIcon size={30}/>
                <span className={'actions-toggle ' + (this.state.height >= 0 ? '' : 'rotated') }><ChevronDownIcon/></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
  }

export default Allumni
```

thank you

Comment: looks related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642191/react-childrens-render-method-starts-after-parents-render-method-has-fin

Comment: thank you @Kamran, can you please explain me what do I need to do to fix this, I can't follow the GitHub conversation completely

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly the problem but I noticed `key={graduate.id}` in the `Allumni` `map` should be in the wrapper element, `div` in this case.